# Help needed with Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript

I need some help with Javascript objects.  This is what I've got:

```
_genre_id = {politics:'1',sport:'2',celeb:'3',gossip:'4',busi:'5'};
var genre = 'politics';
```

What I want to accomplish would be to simply get the value stored for politics, in this case 1 by doing something like this:

```
var genreID = _genre_id.genre;
```

But this of course doesn't work because the genre property doesn't exist.  I want it to relate to _genre_id.politics.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about `_genre_id[genre]`?

Answer (score 7):

```
var _genre_id = {politics:'1',sport:'2',celeb:'3',gossip:'4',busi:'5'};
var genre = 'politics';
var genreID = _genre_id[genre];
```

Note that I added `var` before setting `_genre_id`, so that it gets declared in the current scope, without declaring it, you end up setting `window._genre_id` instead of a local variable.